# No executable found matching command "bower"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, appveyor

I run this command on AppVeyor:

```
 dotnet publish .\src\ReviewerServices.web -c Release
```

ReviewerServices.web is the folder containing my .NET MVC app and I want to create all the files to publish on IIS

Unfortunately, what I get is:

[image]

locally I get the same error. Do I need to install bower? npm install -g bower?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I had to install bower and gulp

```
npm install -g bower
npm install -g gulp
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem.

need to install bower and gulp as a global packages.

> npm install -g bower
>
> npm install -g gulp